# Using the Node JS got() library, how do you select elements other than the body?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I've tried several different things and each one's result is undefined. My attempts are included below:

```
function readHTTP(sm){
    const file = '/Users/codel/OneDrive/Documents/BattlEye/files/temp.txt'
    const url= 'https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/' + sm[1];
    (async () => {
        try {
            const page = await got(url);
            console.log(page.div);
            console.log(page.body.class);
            console.log(page.body.div);
            console.log(page.class);
            console.log(page.class);
            console.log(page.class);
            console.log(page.class);
            let content = page.body;
            fs.writeFile(file, content, err => {
                if (err) {
                  console.error(err)
                  return
                }
            });
        } catch (error){
            console.log(error.page.class);
        }
    })();
}
```

The only reason why I need to select a certain element is so that I do not have to write the response to a temp file, then parse it from there it seems inefficient, especially if there is a way to select a certain element such as:

```
<div class="trn-defstat__name">Level</div>
<span class="trn-text--dimmed">Ranked</span>
<div data-stat="PVPKDRatio" class="trn-defstat__value">
<div data-stat="PVPWLRatio" class="trn-defstat__value">
<div data-stat="RankedKDRatio" class="trn-defstat__value">
<div data-stat="RankedWLRatio" class="trn-defstat__value">
```

These elements are within the body, but I just don't know how to individually select the elements. Can someone explain if there is a way to do this or identify the most efficient way of doing this?

Edit: The usage of cheerio in this context ended up throwing errors whenever I tried to connect to the URL. I am most likely using an incorrect style in this context but here is my code:

```
function readHTTP(sm){
    console.log('level');
    console.log('levelText');
    var url= 'https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/' + sm[1];
    request(url,function(err,resp,body){
        if(!error){
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var level = $('.trn-defstat__value');
            var levelText = level.text();
            console.log(level);
            console.log(levelText);
        }
    })
}
```

which throws the error:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:617:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:493:23)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:493:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

After researching a little bit about cheerio, I found an alternative - puppeteer, which awaits for the page to be loaded to request a response. Here is my usage of that library:

```
function readHTTP(sm){
     const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
     var url= 'https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/' + sm[1];
     (async() => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);
        const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.trn-defstat__value'))
                    .map(item => item.innerText);
        }); 
        writeStatFile(m,cc,sm,data)
    })();
}
```

It works pretty well and receives all the data I need to grab from the HTML code. But my question still stands is there a faster and more efficient way to do this?

*My current method takes about 3/2 seconds to return all the data in the console.*

Comment: I suppose you need to use something like `cheerio` instead of `got`

Comment: @Anatoly I am trying cheerio but I seem to be throwing the error: 'socket hang up' and 'error event on ClientRequest instance at'. Would cheerio be the most efficient way to do this is my question.

Comment: Using cheerio you don't need to parse HTML manually that's what I'm trying to say